# Using node package manager, why might it install many unwanted modules?

Tags: npm, gulp

I'm looking to use Gulp and a few plugins. The package.json lists the dependencies correctly, but if I do `npm install` locally my node_modules folder gets filled to the brim. If I try to install a single package locally, node_modules ends up including more than 60 other folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because each dependancy described in package.json are themselves modules which have other module dependancies. So the whole tree gets pulled in when you install the module dependancies.